# How can this inequality be solved

Tags: real-analysis

if $$0<x<y<$$ or$$ x>y>1$$
then how can I show than
$$\frac{x^{y^x}}{y^{x^y}}>\frac{x}{y}>\frac{x^y}{y^x}$$
i tried but I got no insight whatsoever.Kindly tell me can I slove this problem.

Comment: edit your question @rayees

Comment: @Boris Sir I dont know how to write it

Comment: @RayeesAhmad do you want $$\frac{x^{y^x}}{y^{x^y}}$$

Comment: yes thank u sir...

Comment: this problem has really taken sweat and blood out of me...Please someone give a hint